# How can i send data from Form to localStorage in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

im new to Laravel, and im needing to grab a value from a Form and send it to LocalStorage, but I cannot find anything on internet to achieve this. There is some way?

Comment: normally the form would be submitted via an http post to a store route within your laravel application. In the controller for that route, you could process the posted data and store it to the database. Is the kind of thing you have in mind?

Comment: on submitting a form, do you want to store value in local storage?

Comment: Yeah, is that posible?